# OpenLayers Color an SVG Icon

Tags: jquery, svg, openlayers

I have been following the Icon Colors example on the OpenLayers site, http://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/icon-color.html?q=color.

This works well for me with png and jpg images, however when I switch to using svg images the color does not change at all. There are no errors. The color just does not change.

Here is the snippet of code where the color change happens:

```
    /*set the colour*/
    var style = new ol.style.Style({
        image: new ol.style.Icon(/** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
            anchor: [0.5, 0.5],
            src : 'img/icons/example.svg',
            color: '#8959A8'
        }))
    });
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Post the whole code in Plunckr. I checked myself its working for SVG. One more thing whether image is getting loaded?

Comment: Hi @Sumanth, thanks for replying. I have narrowed down the issue to the svg itself. For example this svg works: '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="120" height="120" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<circle fill="#FFFFFF" cx="60" cy="60" r="60"/>
</svg>' but the svg I have with '<path fill="#191817" d="M305.1,433.4h-3.8c0.5,0.2,1.1,0.2,1.9,0.2C304,433.7,304.6,433.6,305.1,433.4z"/>' etc does not.

Answer (score 13):

Apparently the `fill` property for your SVG needs to be *white* (`#fff`). The doc doesn't say anything about this but my conclusion is that any white (`#fff`) will be colorized with the value passed to the `color` attribute, independently of the type of the image.

Comment: The docs now mention that color adds a 'tint' to your original marker. https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_style_Icon-Icon.html 

I believe this is so that it also works with PNG, JPEG etc. I've yet to find a way to keep part of an SVG white and change the colour on the rest.